# How do I force the ReSharper test runner to run tests sequentially?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, resharper

Is it possible to force the ReSharper 5.1 unit test runner to run all tests sequentially? I cannot run the tests in parallel (some integration tests in the solution change the database and so other tests fail).

Comment: In options for Resharper make sure that in Tools\Unit testing you have only 1 assembly to run in parallel. Tests from single assembly should run sequentially.

Comment: I can select 'Unit testing providers'. What do you mean by ' you have only 1 assembly to run in parallel'?

Comment: Which version of resharper are you using?

Comment: Currently I'm using Resharper 5.1

Answer (score 1):

To run the tests sequentially add the sequential attribute to the tests.

```
[Test, Sequential]
```

For more information about the Sequential Attribute see http://nunit.org/docs/2.6.4/sequential.html